# jQuery Load don't realod script inside page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a popup that reload the content after a click. 
I usa jQuery `.load` to reload the content.
Code in short:

```
var posting = $.post(url, $form.serialize());
posting.done(function(data) {    
   $('.modal-body .content').load(window.location.href + " .modal-body .content"),
}
```

In this way I can refresh only the popup content with the new data.
But the popup have also a script, this script is not load.

This script is inside a PHP because I need to populate it.

```
<?php
    foreach ($items as $p){
        var $myVar = array(...)
    }


echo '
  <script>
     ...
     '. $myVar .'
     ...
  </script>';

?>
```

Now, how can I load this script inside the popup?
I can not load a external js file because I need the PHP variable. I can't use `.load`. I try to use a `Ajax` but I'am not sure how I can do.

Comment: scripts delivered via AJAX don't get executed. Instead, write the script in your main page, and make it read the value from a hidden field (rather than hard-coding the value). Deliver the hidden field (and value) inside the HTML returned from the .load() function. That way whenever the script runs it will always read the current value from the page.

Comment: @ADyson, thank, it's interesting idea. Now I try.